# The fomat and extension of "file.csv" doesn't match

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi, export-to-csv

I am trying to create the csv file with data as follows

```
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
        String fileLocation = null;
        try { 
            // Set the header columns name for worksheet
            createHeader(workbook, sheet);
            // populate the data
            createWorkbookRows(ker, sheet, kerList, AerList);

            String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
            File file = new File(tempDir);
            fileLocation = file.getAbsolutePath() + FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator() + "MyData.csv";
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
```

With the above code I am able to generate the csv file, but when I try to open the file the below error it is showing

[image]

When I click on `yes` it is showing the data properly in excel file.

I have verified the csv file by opening in `Notepad++` also it is showing in non understandable language instead of comma seperated.

Please suggest how can I solve the above issue.

Comment: check your csv file

Comment: @Stultuske The generated file is showing correct data, but before opening it is showing the error, I want to eliminate that error.

Comment: You have created an excel file so use an excel file extension in the name and not .csv

Comment: the requirement is to generate the csv file. how to change the file to csv only

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook.write` does not write `CSV` but `Excel` in `Office Open XML` format. So the file would must be named `*.xlsx` instead of `*.csv`.  `Apache poi` will **not** generate `CSV` fiiles. There are multiple other libraries to do this.

Comment: a simple text writer should be sufficient to create a csv

Comment: If you should create a csv file then don’t use excel classes, it’s as simple as that. Either create an ordinary text file and write the content as strings to it or use some csv library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POI writes a binary Excel file. Your extension "csv" is wrong. It should be "xlsx" because you use XSSFWorkbook.

Comment: the requirement is to generate the csv file. how to change the file to csv only

Comment: Use a different library to do that. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for example. Use the right tools for the right job.

Comment: As suggested I have used the OpenCSV, I can able to generate the csv file...