# CSV file showing warning when open after convert to new csv (C#)

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

I am reading a CSV file which is having content type(mime type) that is "application/vnd.ms-excel" and updating the necessary details and creating a new file (CSV) and putting those data in a new file.

Reading the data using File:

```
var newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Create a new file using XSSFWorkbook:

```
IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(Path.GetFileName(newFileName));
```

Save the file using File:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //output excel file
                workbook.Write(file);
                file.Close();
            }
```

The file is created successfully but when trying to open the file it is throwing a warning message as below:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. If any mistake I am doing please correct.

Comment: I would imagine that the file is not a CSV file, as the error message suggests. It's probably an XLSX file, so give the file an extension that matches the format. You can use the `Path.ChangeExtension` method to change the extension on a file path/name.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have used the same to change the extension but having the same issue.

Comment: have you looked in the actual file with notepad, how it looks like?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Yes, with the notepad file when I try to copy and paste into the notepad and then copy from notepad and paste into a new CSV file it is confirming that "The data you're pasting isn't the same size as your selection. Do you want to paste it anyway?"

Comment: can you paste an example of the written result in your question?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The fomat and extension of "file.csv" doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542108/the-fomat-and-extension-of-file-csv-doesnt-match)

Comment: @FalcoAlexander yes your last comment could be the solution thanks.